# What are the Coldest Temperatures Reached without Laser Cooling

Tags: thermodynamics

I see that a dilution fridge + nuclear magnetic cooling can get you to microKelvin.  Is this the max?

I'm also guessing that this might also be the same question as what is the coldest temperature of a non-gas material?